# Writing a pandas dataframes as a feather or parquet file converts the list values into numpy arrays

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I was writing pandas dataframes to disk using `pd.to_feather()` and I noticed that after reading them back, some code that worked previously, now failed. I just checked and the reason is that my original dataframe has some columns with type `list` values, and those values get converted to type `numpy.ndarray` when writing them to feather (or parquet), so reading them back from feather doesn't produce the same original types.

I read in the pyarrow documentation and search in the pandas issues, but i didn't find anything. My solution is to write dataframes as pickle files, but those are 4 times bigger. I'm not sure if this is a bug, but also, converting types without any warning seems like it.

I'm in `pandas 1.4.4` and `pyarrow 9.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the standard behaviour of pyarrow to represent `list` arrays as numpy array when converting an arrow table to pandas.

You can write some simple python code to convert your list columns from `np.ndarray`  to `list`

```py
import pyarrow.feather

table = pyarrow.feather.read_table('file.feather')

df = table.to_pandas()

for field in table.schema:
    if pa.types.is_list(field.type):
        df[field.name] = df[field.name].apply(list)
```